# Order by one of two aliases (for relationships of the same table)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have the tables users and projects.

Projects has:

```
project_manager_id -> references users.id
business_manager_id -> references users.id
```

I have to order by one of those. So, my query is:

```
select * from projects...
LEFT JOIN profiles project_managers ON project_managers.id = projects.project_manager_id
LEFT JOIN profiles business_managers ON business_managers.id = projects.project_manager_id
order by project_managers.name
```

OR

```
order by business_managers.name
```

But for both order by, the result is the same. My result is ordered by the first profiles.name JOIN (project_managers.name).

How can I order it correctly, by project_managers.name or business_manager.name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would work

```
select * from (
    select projects.id project_id 
    , project_managers.name project_managers_name
    , business_managers.name business_managers_name
    , ...
    from projects
    LEFT JOIN profiles project_managers 
    ON project_managers.id = projects.project_manager_id
    LEFT JOIN profiles business_managers 
    ON business_managers.id = projects.project_manager_id
) projects
order by project_managers_name
```

Comment: Your solution cleared my sight to do a projection with aliases and it worked! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
order by coalesce(project_managers.name, business_manager.name)
```

You are using `left join`, so this assumes that one of the values is `NULL`.

Comment: I never do an order by both at same time